# Swift 4.2: Cannot convert value of type 'Notification' to expected argument type 'Notification'

Tags: swift

I can't understand what's wrong with code.
I use native method for final merge context.

```
@objc func mergeContext(notification: Notification) {
        let sender = notification.managedObjectContext

        if sender != mainThreadManagedObjectContext {
            mainThreadManagedObjectContext.performAndWait {
                [unowned self] in

           self.mainThreadManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: paste your code instead of screenshots

Comment: Unrelated but honestly, I don't think it is a good idea to show a "middle-finger" when posting a question (or even an answer!) .

Comment: Do you have a custom class `Notification`?

Comment: No. Its new project)

Comment: @AhmadF Sorry. But it's old Facebook account:) I don't use him and forget my avatar.

Comment: as @vadian said I think you have a class/structure named `Notification`. Or how can you get `notification.managedObjectContext`? May be any other frameworks that you are using will have one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here Notification clearly is a subclass of NSManagedObject

```
let sender = notification.managedObjectContext
```

but this method `mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave:)` expects a swift class [`Notification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notification) so you are probably calling the wrong function

Comment: Thanks! I found CoreData object class with name "Notification" :) I created and forget about this.